# Creating a WCF service using http

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

I'm trying to simulate an existing API and I would love to get some help.

How can I create a WCF service that will respond to:
`http://www.something.com/dothis?param1=x&param2=y`

And will run the function `dothis` with the given parameters' values. And then it needs to return an XML response.

I looked it up but I would love to get some directions, links or better search terms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) for nice REST WCF services.

The main thing you need to know is about the interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMSDNMagazineService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="/")]
    IssuesCollection GetAllIssues();
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{year}")]
    IssuesData GetIssuesByYear(string year);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{year}/{issue}")]
    Articles GetIssue(string year, string issue);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{year}/{issue}/{article}")]
    Article GetArticle(string year, string issue, string article);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{year}/{issue}",Method="POST")]
    Article AddArticle(string year, string issue, Article article);

}
```

The WebInvoke attribute will get you what you want while using a nice url.  So you would end up with something like http://www.something.com/dothis/x/y.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at UriTemplate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx